# python openpyxl unicode error

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a problem with writing into xlsx file. I am getting the **openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalCharacterError** error. On the top of my code there is written:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Also the line that raises the error is:

```
 ws[name_line] = z.text.encode('utf-8').strip()
```

So now I really don`t know what to do.

Comment: What if you define a variable `temp = z.text.encode('utf-8').strip()`. Then you do `print temp` or look at your debugger to find out what `temp` is?

Comment: It prints the variable normally just it does not want to enter the same data to the file.

Comment: The header line has nothing to do with this; it is only a means to tell the interpreter the encoding of your source.  You are trying to put a byte array (after `.encode()`) into an `openpyxl` structure.  Maybe it doesn't like this.  Have you tried putting a unicode directly (simply without using `.encode()`) instead?

Comment: What is `z.text` btw? a (unicode) string?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  Can you tell us how to get your `ws` and what `name_line` is?

Comment: My guess: do this `unicode(z.text).strip()`.

Comment: I am basically scraping a website with selenium and saving the data to a xlsx file using openpyxl. ws = wb.active. The line that the file brakes is: José Manuel García. name_line = 'C' + str(line) (line - cells number). z - data from the list (inside loop)

Comment: You should not be encoding the text at all.

Answer (score 0):

The *IllegalCharacterError Exception* raises when you want to assing special character to a Cell.
You don't have to encode Strings by yourself, `openpyxl` always encodes to *utf-8*.

Change your code, for instance to:

```
ws['A1'] = z.text.strip()
```

Come back and Flag your Question as answered if this is working for you or comment why not.